# Are the following two presentations of the dicyclic group the same:

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Are the following two presentations of the dicyclic group the same:

$\mathrm{Dic}_n=\{a^{2n}=1=b^4: ab=ba^{-1}\}$
and
$\mathrm{Dic}_n=\{a^{2n}=1=b^4: bab^{-1}=a^{-1}\}$.

I am confused on how to obtain the relation $ab=ba^{-1}$ from $bab^{-1}=a^{-1}$  and vice versa.

Is there any way to get this? Please help me out.

Comment: These presentations define isomorphic groups of order $8n$, but they are not dicyclic groups. For the dicyclic group you need the additional relation $a^n=b^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$bab^{-1}=a^{-1} \implies ab^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}
\implies ab^{-1}={(ab)}^{-1}$

Taking inverse on both sides we get;

$(ab^{-1})^{-1}=({(ab)}^{-1})^{-1}
\implies ba^{-1}=ab$

Comment: +1.  I would just add that this whole process is reversible, so in fact $bab^{-1} = a^{-1} \iff ba^{-1} = ab$.